# Android: Use Button click to iterate through different messages

Tags: java, android, button

My code calls the below message generating method multiple times throughout its execution but I want to iterate through each message via a button press. How do I stop the execution of the program each time it calls this method until the button is pressed?

```
private void printMessage(String text){

    if(!text.equals("")){
        mainAdapter.add(0, text);
        layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if "stopping the execution of the program" is what you would want to do because you can't actually click on anything if the app is suspended.

You most android views have a `.setClickable(boolean)` and a `.setEnabled(boolean)` function.  You could call that on everything you don't want them interacted with and then re-enable when necessary.